# php add days to date in PHP

Tags: php

I want to add or remove a day (or more) depending on a dynamic value. Some times i want to remove / add 4 days, and next time maybe 9. How would i be able to do this in PHP? I was hoping there was i timestamp solution so i could use number of secounds.

Example: 2012-04-21 + 86400 // Add one day

Is there any good solution for this? or is there other good methods where i can use dynamic values to remove or add any number of days i wanted.

Please feel free to suggest!

Comment: The number of seconds 24 hours have

Comment: if 100000 seconds are added then how many days are add 1 or 2 ?

Comment: please use the search function before asking duplicates like you agreed to do in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice - This question has been answered often enough already: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+days+php

Comment: @Gordon, exactly. Doing a google search as simple as https://www.google.com/search?q=php+add+day would already have solved this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at strtotime()

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
$unix_time = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime("2012-11-01"));
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unix_time);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use strtotime

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($old_date . ' +1 day'));
```

Comment: how would i do that dynamicly? i guess i can't use $date = strtotime($old_date . " +$days day");

Comment: you can use it, try. Number of days you can set your. ..($old_date . "+{$num_of_days} day"));